# Communication between two android phones apart from each other

Tags: android, communication

I am developing two android applications, lets call them application A and application B.
I am going to deploy application A on one phone and application B on other phone.

Both applications using the gps for location tracking.

on application B i am going to set the current location of phone. when the current location of application B changes i want to activate or send any notification to  the application A deployed on other phone. want to track the current position of application B(other phone) from application A.

distance between two phone might be in Km. Please give me sugggestion how i can go ahead.

package com.password.authentication;

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Registration implements ActionListener,MouseListener {

    private JFrame registrationFrame;
    private JLabel userNameLabel;
    private JTextField userNameText;
    private JLabel firstNameLabel;
    private JTextField firstNameText;
    private JLabel lastNameLabel;
    private JTextField lastNameText;
    private JLabel emailID;
    private JTextField emailIDText;
    private JLabel password;
    private JLabel imagePassword;
    private JButton reset;
    private JButton register;
    private int xCordinate;
    private int yCordinate;
    private int imageCount;
    private int labelWidth;
    private int textFieldWidth;
    private int height;
    private List<JTextField> allTextFiel;
    private List<String> allPoints=new ArrayList<String>();

    File[] files={new File("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg"),
             new File("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Chrysanthemum.jpg"),
             new File("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Hydrangeas.jpg")};

    public Registration()
    {
        imageCount=0;
        xCordinate=10;
        yCordinate=10;
        labelWidth=100;
        textFieldWidth=180;
        height=30;
        allTextFiel=new ArrayList<JTextField>();
        registrationFrame=new JFrame("Registration");
        registrationFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        registrationFrame.setLayout(null);

        userNameLabel=new JLabel("UserName");
        userNameLabel.setBounds(xCordinate, yCordinate, labelWidth, height);
        registrationFrame.add(userNameLabel);

        userNameText=new JTextField();
        userNameText.setBounds(userNameLabel.getX()+userNameLabel.getWidth()+10, yCordinate, textFieldWidth, height);
        registrationFrame.add(userNameText);
        allTextFiel.add(userNameText);

        yCordinate=userNameLabel.getHeight()+20;

        firstNameLabel=new JLabel("First Name");
        firstNameLabel.setBounds(xCordinate, yCordinate, labelWidth, height);
        registrationFrame.add(firstNameLabel);

        firstNameText=new JTextField();
        firstNameText.setBounds(firstNameLabel.getX()+firstNameLabel.getWidth()+10, yCordinate, textFieldWidth, height);
        registrationFrame.add(firstNameText);
        allTextFiel.add(firstNameText);
        yCordinate=yCordinate+firstNameLabel.getHeight()+20;


        lastNameLabel=new JLabel("Last Name");
        lastNameLabel.setBounds(xCordinate, yCordinate, labelWidth, height);
        registrationFrame.add(lastNameLabel);
        lastNameText=new JTextField();
        lastNameText.setBounds(lastNameLabel.getX()+lastNameLabel.getWidth()+10, yCordinate, textFieldWidth,height);
        registrationFrame.add(lastNameText);
        allTextFiel.add(lastNameText);

        yCordinate=yCordinate+lastNameLabel.getHeight()+20;

        emailID=new JLabel("EmailID");
        emailID.setBounds(xCordinate, yCordinate, labelWidth, height);
        registrationFrame.add(emailID);

        emailIDText=new JTextField();
        emailIDText.setBounds(emailID.getX()+emailID.getWidth()+10, yCordinate, textFieldWidth, height);
        registrationFrame.add(emailIDText);

        allTextFiel.add(emailIDText);
        yCordinate=yCordinate+emailID.getHeight()+20;

        password=new JLabel("password");
        password.setBounds(xCordinate, yCordinate, labelWidth,height);
        registrationFrame.add(password);



         BufferedImage img;
            try {


                img = ImageIO.read(files[imageCount]);
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
                imagePassword=new JLabel(icon);
                imagePassword.setBounds(password.getX()+password.getWidth()+10, yCordinate, 250, 200);
                registrationFrame.add(imagePassword);
                imagePassword.addMouseListener(this);

            }
             catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            yCordinate=yCordinate+imagePassword.getHeight()+20;
            register=new JButton("Register");
            register.setBounds(imagePassword.getX(), yCordinate, 100, height);
            registrationFrame.add(register);
            register.addActionListener(this);

            reset=new JButton("reset");
            reset.setBounds(register.getX()+register.getWidth()+10, yCordinate, 100,30);
            registrationFrame.add(reset);
            reset.addActionListener(this);

            registrationFrame.setSize(600,600);
            registrationFrame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            registrationFrame.setVisible(true);
    }





    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==register)
    {
        int totalImagesSelected=imageCount;
        if(totalImagesSelected==3)

        {
            for(String XYPosition:allPoints)
            {
                System.out.println("point position are "+XYPosition);
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(registrationFrame, "Registered SuccessFully" );
            registrationFrame.dispose();


        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(registrationFrame, "Please select region from all images" );
        }

    }
    if(e.getSource()==reset)
    {
        for (JTextField field : allTextFiel) {
            field.setText("");
          }

    }

    }





    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        int selectedXcordinate=e.getX();
        int selectedYcordinate=e.getY();
        String XYPosition=selectedXcordinate+","+selectedYcordinate;
        allPoints.add(XYPosition);
        imageCount=imageCount+1;
        int x=imagePassword.getX();
        int y=imagePassword.getY();
        int imagewidth=imagePassword.getWidth();
        int imageheight=imagePassword.getHeight();

        if(imageCount<files.length)
        {
        registrationFrame.remove(imagePassword);
        BufferedImage img;
        try {


            img = ImageIO.read(files[imageCount]);

            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
            imagePassword=new JLabel(icon);
            imagePassword.setBounds(x,y ,imagewidth, imageheight);
            registrationFrame.add(imagePassword);
            imagePassword.addMouseListener(this);
            registrationFrame.repaint();

        }
         catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    }





    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }





    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }





    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }





    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.io.File;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;

    public class Welcome implements ActionListener {

         private JFrame frame;
         private JLabel welcome;
         private JButton login;
         private JButton admin;
         private JButton registration;
         private int xCordinate;
         private int yCordinate;

        public Welcome()
        {
                xCordinate=10;
                yCordinate=10;
                frame=new JFrame("Welcome");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(null);
                welcome=new JLabel("Welcome to Password Authentication Using Image");
                login=new JButton("Login");
                admin=new JButton("Admin Login");
                registration=new JButton("Registration");
                welcome.setBounds(xCordinate, yCordinate, 400, 30);
                frame.add(welcome);
                yCordinate=yCordinate+40;
                login.setBounds(xCordinate, yCordinate, 120, 30);
                frame.add(login);
                yCordinate=yCordinate+40;
                admin.setBounds(xCordinate, yCordinate, 120, 30);
                frame.add(admin);
                yCordinate=yCordinate+40;
                registration.setBounds(xCordinate, yCordinate, 120, 30);
                frame.add(registration);
                login.addActionListener(this);
                admin.addActionListener(this);
                registration.addActionListener(this);

                frame.setSize(500,400);
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);

        }


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource()==login)
        {
            Login login=new Login();
        }
        if(e.getSource()==admin)
        {
            AdminLogin admin=new AdminLogin();
            //UploadImages uploadImage=new UploadImages();
        }
        if(e.getSource()==registration)
        {
            Registration registration=new Registration();
        }

        }
        public static void main(String[] args )
        {
            Welcome welcomeScreen=new Welcome();

        }

    }

    package com.password.authentication;

    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;

    public class Login implements ActionListener,MouseListener {
        private JFrame loginFrame;
        private JLabel heading;
        private JLabel userNameLabel;
        private JTextField userName;
        private JLabel PasswordLabel;
        private JLabel image;
        private JButton submitt;
        private JButton reset;
        private int xCordinate;
        private int yCordinate;
        private int height;
        private int imageCount;
        private List<JTextField> allTextField;
        File[] files={new File("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg"),
                 new File("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Chrysanthemum.jpg"),
                 new File("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Hydrangeas.jpg")};

        public int getxCordinate() {
            return xCordinate;
        }


        public void setxCordinate(int xCordinate) {
            this.xCordinate = xCordinate;
        }


        public int getyCordinate() {
            return yCordinate;
        }


        public void setyCordinate(int yCordinate) {
            this.yCordinate = yCordinate;
        }


        public Login()
        {   
            imageCount=0;
            height=30;
            xCordinate=10;
            yCordinate=10;
            allTextField=new ArrayList<JTextField>();
            loginFrame=new JFrame("Login");
            loginFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            loginFrame.setLayout(null);
            heading=new JLabel("Enter Login Credentials");
            heading.setBounds(xCordinate, yCordinate, 180, 30);
            loginFrame.add(heading);

            yCordinate=yCordinate+height+10;

            userNameLabel=new JLabel("UserName");
            userNameLabel.setBounds(xCordinate, yCordinate, 100, height);
            loginFrame.add(userNameLabel);


            userName=new JTextField();
            userName.setBounds(userNameLabel.getX()+userNameLabel.getWidth()+10, yCordinate, 180, height);
            loginFrame.add(userName);
            allTextField.add(userName);

            yCordinate=yCordinate+height+10;

            PasswordLabel=new JLabel("Password");
            PasswordLabel.setBounds(xCordinate, yCordinate, 100, height);
            loginFrame.add(PasswordLabel);


             BufferedImage img;
            try {


                img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg"));

                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
                image=new JLabel(icon);
                image.setBounds(PasswordLabel.getX()+PasswordLabel.getWidth()+10, yCordinate, 250, 200);

                loginFrame.add(image);
                image.addMouseListener(this);

            }
             catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            yCordinate=yCordinate+image.getHeight()+10;
            submitt=new JButton("Submit");
            submitt.setBounds(image.getX(), yCordinate, 120, height);
            loginFrame.add(submitt);

            reset=new JButton("Reset");
            reset.setBounds(submitt.getX()+submitt.getWidth()+10, yCordinate, 120, height);
            loginFrame.add(reset);

            loginFrame.setSize(500,400);
            loginFrame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            loginFrame.setVisible(true);
        }


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(e.getSource()==reset)
            {
                for (JTextField field : allTextField) {
                    field.setText("");
                  }

            }

        }


        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            imageCount=imageCount+1;
            int x=image.getX();
            int y=image.getY();
            int imagewidth=image.getWidth();
            int imageheight=image.getHeight();

            if(imageCount<files.length)
            {
                loginFrame.remove(image);
            BufferedImage img;
            try {


                img = ImageIO.read(files[imageCount]);

                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
                image=new JLabel(icon);
                image.setBounds(x,y ,imagewidth, imageheight);
                loginFrame.add(image);
                image.addMouseListener(this);
                loginFrame.repaint();

            }
             catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            }



        }


        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

package com.password.authentication;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class AdminLogin implements ActionListener {

        JFrame adminLoginFrame;
        JLabel welcomeMessage;
        JLabel userNameLabel;
        JLabel passwordLabel;
        JTextField usernameText;
        JTextField passwordText;
        JButton submit;
        JButton reset;
        int xCordinate;
        int yCordinate;
        int labelWidth;
        int height;
        int textWidth;

    public AdminLogin()
    {
        labelWidth=120;
        textWidth=180;
        height=30;
        xCordinate=30;
        yCordinate=30;
        adminLoginFrame=new JFrame(" Admin Login");
        adminLoginFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        adminLoginFrame.setLayout(null);
        welcomeMessage=new JLabel("Admin Login");
        welcomeMessage.setBounds(xCordinate, yCordinate, labelWidth, height);
        adminLoginFrame.add(welcomeMessage);
        yCordinate=yCordinate+welcomeMessage.getHeight()+10;
        userNameLabel=new JLabel("UserName");
        userNameLabel.setBounds(xCordinate, yCordinate, labelWidth, height);
        adminLoginFrame.add(userNameLabel);
        usernameText=new JTextField();
        usernameText.setBounds(xCordinate+userNameLabel.getWidth()+10, yCordinate, textWidth, height);
        adminLoginFrame.add(usernameText);
        yCordinate=yCordinate+usernameText.getHeight()+10;
        passwordLabel=new JLabel("Password");
        passwordLabel.setBounds(xCordinate, yCordinate, labelWidth, height);
        adminLoginFrame.add(passwordLabel);
        passwordText=new JTextField();
        passwordText.setBounds(xCordinate+passwordLabel.getWidth()+10, yCordinate, textWidth, height);
        adminLoginFrame.add(passwordText);
        yCordinate=yCordinate+passwordText.getHeight()+10;
        submit=new JButton("Submit");
        submit.setBounds(xCordinate+passwordLabel.getWidth()+10, yCordinate, 100, 30);
        adminLoginFrame.add(submit);
        submit.addActionListener(this);
        reset=new JButton("reset");
        reset.setBounds(xCordinate+passwordText.getX()+submit.getWidth(), yCordinate, 100, 30);
        adminLoginFrame.add(reset);
        adminLoginFrame.setSize(500,400);
        adminLoginFrame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        adminLoginFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==submit)
        {
            new UnLockUser();
        }

    }


}


package com.password.authentication;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class UnLockUser  implements ActionListener {

    public JFrame unLockUserFrame;
    private JLabel heading;
    private JLabel userName;
    private JLabel userID;
    int xCordinate;
    int yCordinate;

    public  List<String> lockedUser=new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<JCheckBox> selectedCheckBoxes=new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();

    public UnLockUser()
    {
            unLockUserFrame=new JFrame("UnLock Users");
            unLockUserFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            unLockUserFrame.setLayout(null);
            xCordinate=70;
            yCordinate=40;
            lockedUser.add("nagesh_112");
            lockedUser.add("piyush_223");
            heading=new JLabel("Locked Users");
            heading.setForeground(Color.RED);
            heading.setBounds(xCordinate, 30, 120, 30);
            unLockUserFrame.add(heading);
            yCordinate=yCordinate+30;
            userID=new JLabel("UserID");
            userID.setBounds(xCordinate+20, yCordinate, 80, 30);
            unLockUserFrame.add(userID);
            userName=new JLabel("UserName");
            userName.setBounds(xCordinate+userID.getWidth(), yCordinate, 100, 30);
            unLockUserFrame.add(userName);


        for(int i=0;i<lockedUser.size();i++)
        {
            String userDetails=lockedUser.get(i);
            String[] user=userDetails.split("_");
            String userID=user[1];
            JCheckBox unlockUser=new JCheckBox("  "+userID);
            yCordinate=yCordinate+30;
            unlockUser.setBounds(xCordinate, yCordinate, 60, 30);
            unLockUserFrame.add(unlockUser);
            JLabel userName=new JLabel(user[0]);
            userName.setBounds(xCordinate+unlockUser.getWidth()+10, yCordinate, 100, 30);
            unLockUserFrame.add(userName);
            selectedCheckBoxes.add(unlockUser);
        }
            yCordinate=yCordinate+30;
            JButton unLock=new JButton("UnLock");
            unLock.setBounds(xCordinate, yCordinate+20, 100, 30);
            unLock.addActionListener(this);
            unLockUserFrame.add(unLock);
            unLockUserFrame.setSize(500,400);
            unLockUserFrame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            unLockUserFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            for (JCheckBox checkBox : selectedCheckBoxes) {
                if (checkBox.isSelected())
                {
                    System.out.println("seleetd checkbox value is"+checkBox.getText());
                }
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you not need some kind of 'middle man', a server or something for the app to read GPS update long and lat from?

Comment: @matty357: i am able to read the gps cordinate on both the phones.

Comment: I am developing two applications one is for Car device(assuming Car has android device) and another is for customer. when i park the car i will set the car device  current coordinate . when any occurrence of car theft lets say someone is moving my car that means my cars coordinates are moving then i want to send notification to customer device " saying car is moving" like this. How i can send notification two other android device?

Comment: Thats what i meant by middle man server sorry, some where to put the data so the other device can get it. Dont think you will be able to directly send it from one device to another.

Comment: @matty357: what would be the better option to put data? any database?but using database might cause performance issue.

Comment: You can try using sockets, but I presume its a lot of work to get it perfect and reliable. Personally i would update the long/lat to a database and have the other device read it from there.

Comment: @matty357: But matty it might add overhead on database. to read and write into database at a same time might cause performance issue if users increase.  what  about the push notification option? will it  be reliable?

Comment: https://yalantis.com/blog/push-notifications-mechanism-outline-ios-and-android/
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/